# Unable to pass args to context.job_queue.run_once in Python Telegram bot API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In the following code how can we pass the `context.args` and `context` to another function, in this case `callback_search_msgs`

```
def search_msgs(update, context):
    print('In TG, args', context.args)
    context.job_queue.run_once(callback_search_msgs, 1, context=context, job_kwargs={'keys': context.args})

def callback_search_msgs(context, keys):
    print('Args', keys)
    chat_id = context.job.context
    print('Chat ID ', chat_id)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("search_msgs",search_msgs, pass_job_queue=True,
                                  pass_user_data=True))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few notes:

- job callbacks accept exactly one argument of type `CallbackContext`. Not two.
- the `job_kwargs` parameter is used to pass keywoard argument to the APScheduler backend, on which `JobQueue` is built. The way you're trying to use it doesn't work.
- if you want to know only the `chat_id` in the job, you don't have to pass the whole `context` argument of `search_msgs`. Just do `context.job_queue.run_once(..., context=chat_id,...)`
- if you want to pass both the `chat_id` and `context.args` you can e.g. pass them as tuple:

  ```
  job_queue.run_once(..., context=(chat_id, context.args), ...)
  ```

  and then retrieve them in the job via `chat_id, args = context.job.context`.
- Since you're using `use_context=True` (which is the default in v13+, btw), the `pass_*` parameters of `CommandHandler` (or any other handler) have no effect at all.

I suggest to carefully read

- The [tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) on `JobQueue`
- The [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#timerbotpy) on `JobQueue`
- The [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) of `JobQueue`

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`